Macro nested conditional compilation not working
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT_MESSAGE() \
    do { \
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; \
        #if defined(SOME_CONDITION) \
            std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; \
        #endif \
    } while (0)

int main() {
    PRINT_MESSAGE();

    return 0;
}

main.cpp:4:23: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
    4 | #define PRINT_MESSAGE() \
      |                       ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:14:5: error: 'PRINT_MESSAGE' was not declared in this scope
   14 |     PRINT_MESSAGE();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ (exit status 1)

Can someone see what the problem is？            
How do macros compile with nested conditions？      
Please tell me how to do it.

PRINT_MESSAGE() might simply be a regular function ;-)

You cannot have preprocessor condition (#if) inside the definition of a macro (#define). This is a limitation given by the language.

You can't directly nest a precompiler directive inside of another directive like how you are attempting.
You need to move the #if outside of your #define, eg:
#if defined(SOME_CONDITION)

#define PRINT_MESSAGE() \
    do { \
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; \
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; \
    } while (0)

#else

#define PRINT_MESSAGE() \
    do { \
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; \
    } while (0)

#endif

Alternatively:
#if defined(SOME_CONDITION)
#define PRINT_HELLO_WORLD std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
#else
#define PRINT_HELLO_WORLD
#endif

#define PRINT_MESSAGE() \
    do { \
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; \
        PRINT_HELLO_WORLD \
    } while (0)

